# Please help me understand why SFINAE is not working in this case

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits

Why doesn't this work in VS 2010

```
  typename std::enable_if<!std::has_trivial_destructor<Titem>::value, BOOL>::type
  Clear()
    {
        ...
    }

  typename std::enable_if<std::has_trivial_destructor<Titem>::value, BOOL>::type
  Clear()
    {
        ...
    }
```

It is inside a template class.

I get the following error:

`error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::enable_if<_Test,_Type>'`

on the SFINAE error. Apparently substitution failure IS an error. I know it might just optimize away the destructor call so this isn't a REALLY realistic scenario. Every time I think I've finally understood SFINAE, it still doesn't work when I try to use it.

In response to some comments (concern about overload only by return value), I've changed it to the dummy parameter technique.

**This works:**

```
  template<typename U>
  BOOL _Clear(typename std::enable_if<!std::has_trivial_destructor<U>::value>::type *dummy = 0)
  {
     ...
  }

  template<typename U>
  BOOL _Clear(typename std::enable_if<std::has_trivial_destructor<U>::value>::type *dummy = 0)
  {
     ...
  }

  BOOL Clear()
  {
    return _Clear<Titem>();
  }
```

Conclusion: even members of templates must be forced to templated member functions to do SFINAE in MSVC 2010.

Comment: What line the error is appearing? Also, are you overloading `Clear()` just based on return type? That's not possible.

Comment: Well it's not truely overloading, since only one is valid. The other has a substitution failure. Only one should be considered by the compiler. Obviously something about my understanding is wrong though.

Comment: First Clear definition has the errors. I think the SFINAE one will always fail, there is no ::type (if you know what I mean).

Comment: I went even further with the recommendations and still not working. Updated 2nd code posting with new code.

Comment: Works now, see code at "This works:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone who's not entirely sure about many of the details of SFINAE myself, I'll venture to say the problem is your functions are not templated - thus the compiler is not allowed to discard them even if they turn out to be illegal.

Try

```
template<typename T = Titem>
typename std::enable_if<std::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value, BOOL>::type
Clear()
{
    ...
}

template<typename T = Titem>
typename std::enable_if<!std::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value, BOOL>::type
Clear()
{
    ...
}
```

Edited: Added `Titem` as a default parameter, as per Matthieu M.'s suggestion.

Comment: You are on the right track, but there is simpler: use the ability to default a template parameter => `template <typename T = TItem>`. This way, the method `Clear` is template *but* the user need not bother about it.

Comment: Hey aren't default template parameters on a member function illegal? Only classes (and structs) can have default template parameters, right?

Comment: @doug65536 They are allowed on variadic functions in C++11. I assumed you were using C++11 because std::has_trivial_destructor is part of the new library iirc.

Comment: Yes it is MSVC 2010. It has some C++11 support.

Comment: Since the whole class is a template, the member doesn't need to be a template function as well, does it?

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it led me to the solution, but in my actual implementation I wrapped the template call because 1) I don't want to go put a template parameter at every call site. 2) You cannot default a member function template type. Forcing it to be a template function made it work so I'm accepting your answer. See working code in question after "This works:"